# Olympiad Iterative sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

For each positive integer k > 1, define the sequence ${a_n}$ by
$a_0 = 1$ and
$a_n 
= kn + (−1)^na_{n−1}$ for each
$n\ge 1$.
Determine all values of
k for which 2000 is a term of the
sequence.

This is from BMO 1 2000, the values of k I got were (87,2001,667,3)

Are these all the solutions? how can I go about finding the solutions by induction in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Sorry I posted this before I finished (by accident) I have edited in the question.

Comment: I edited this to use MathJax. Please check to see if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is $k \in \{2001, 667, 87, 23, 3\}$

We have

$a_{4n} = 4nk+1$, 
$a_{4n+1} = k - 1$,
$a_{4n+2} = (4n+3)k - 1$, and
$a_{4n+3} = 1$
which we can prove by induction.

Comment: Thanks! I think that it basically boils down to finding factors of 2001 which are congruent to 3 (mod 4) right?